# Change PageTitle (SP2013)

Tags: 2013, master-page

I have a master page implemented by a vendor but there is one thing I would really like the ability to modify on a page by page basis.

Currently I have a library and have created two distinct views, one with Current Docs, one with Archive Docs. Each have their own aspx page.

I'd like to modify the page title that appears at the top of the page above the content as it simply reads "Documents". Users have no idea whether they are looking at Archives or Current.

Could I put a snippet of html or css on the page to overwrite the page title to append "Archive" to Documents?

When I inspect the page, it is labelled **h1#pageTitle.ms-core-pageTitle** which I Find off because the url is Current.ASPX so why is the page title not Current?
In any case I'd like to overwrite it.

thanks!

Comment: Did you create two aspx pages or you are talking about the aspx pages which gets created as part of views.

Comment: They were created as part of the views.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two webpart pages current and archive, make sure to fill the title field.
2. Add the documents webpart to the page and in the webpart properties select the view corresponding to that page.

Comment: Not ideal but this will work for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your two views for the document library are named `Archive.aspx` and `Current.aspx`, you can use the following Javascript code to get the filename from the URL.

```js
window.location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').replace('.aspx','')
```

Assuming your masterpage/theme comes with jQuery, edit `Archive.aspx` and `Current.aspx` and insert the following jQuery code below the library web part. This code appends the filename of the current view (Archive or Current) to the page title.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1#pageTitle.ms-core-pageTitle")
      .append(' ' + window.location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').replace('.aspx',''))
});
```

Comment: I tried this but no change? <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1#pageTitle.ms-core-pageTitle")
      .append(' ' + window.location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').replace('.aspx',''))
});
</script>

Comment: Is the script running at all? Put a log/alert function in there to see if it works. Alternatively just paste the JS code `$("h1#pageTitle.ms-core-pageTitle") .append(' ' + window.location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').replace('.aspx',''))` in your JS console in Firefox, Chrome or IE and see if the correct target is affected. P.S: Make sure to add the code in a script editor webpart below the library web part in your views.